# Deleting database records in batches

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm looking to execute a delete statement that deletes database rows in a table in batches of 1000.  The command is being called from a powershell script.  The SQL command is below ...

```
USE AIS
GO
DECLARE

   @rows INT = 1,
   @batch_size INT = 1000,
      @duration_in_days INT = -4 

   WHILE @rows > 0
   BEGIN
   --First delete all child rows to avoid FK issues
DELETE TOP (@batch_size)
FROM dbo.ais_audit
WHERE create_time < dateadd(day, @duration_in_days, getdate())
   AND parent_audit_id IS NOT NULL;

   --Now delete any parent rows
   DELETE TOP (@batch_size)
FROM dbo.ais_audit
WHERE create_time < dateadd(day, @duration_in_days, getdate())
   AND parent_audit_id IS NULL;

SELECT @rows = @@ROWCOUNT;    
   SELECT @rows AS 'DELETED ROW COUNT';
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
```

END
"@

The command I'm using to execute this in powershell is

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -AccessToken $tok.Token -Query $command
```

Upon running the above, the first 1000 records get deleted, but then it fails with the following error

```
" Invoke-Sqlcmd : The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint 
"FK_AIS_AUDIT". The conflict occurred in database "AIS", table "dbo.ais_audit", column 
'parent_audit_id'.
The statement has been terminated. "
```

Running the SQL statement from SSMS works fine, so this is only an issue in Powershell it seems.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is any logic in that SQL script to ensure that referential integrity is maintained. It's deleting a bunch of child records. Then it's deleting an arbitrary bunch of parent records without actually checking that the child records no longer exist. I'm suprised this works in SSMS.

Comment: @Nick agreed. Since `TOP` can't have an `ORDER BY` in this scenario, it's quite possible that settings or other differences are leading to a different plan when getting called by PowerShell. In any case, you're right, the fix is to have some protection in the second statement to ensure we're only deleting parents that no longer have children (one way would be to output the parent ids from the first statement, but that would still assume _all_ of a parent's children were deleted in the first 1000). That it currently works in one place but not another is luck, not something to learn from. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your T-SQL, you have no guarantee that the batch of parent rows that you are trying to delete are in any way related to the batch of child rows that you have just deleted. To ensure that you don't have a foreign key conflict, you will need to either:

a) delete all batches of child rows before moving onto deleting the parent rows, or

b) record the list of parent_audit_ids for the batch of child rows that you are deleting & then use this list to delete the associated parent rows.

A is the easier option, but B will allow you to delete children & parent rows in associated batches. Which you choose is dependent on your requirements.

Comment: Our Dev team have adjusted the statement off the back of these suggestions and it's now working as expected.